# How do I get the sidebar to move up 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I have this [page](http://posnation.com/shop_possystems/step2/Table_Service) and I want the sidebar to slide down with the user and it works well but if you are on a small screen like 1024 * 768 you will not see the bottom. Here is some of the code I used to make the sidebar work. Any suggestions on how I can change this behavior.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    sidebar_position();
});
$(window).resize(function(){ 
    sidebar_position();
});


function sidebar_position(){
    var w_width = ($(window).width() -1000) /2;
    $('#sidebar').css('left', w_width);

    var sidebar_height = $('#sidebar').outerHeight();
    var content_height = $('#widecolumn').outerHeight();
    var w_height = $(window).height();

    if ( sidebar_height > w_height) {
        $('#sidebar').css('position', 'absolute');
    } else {
        $('#sidebar').css('position', 'fixed');
    };

    if (sidebar_height > content_height) {
        content_height = sidebar_height;
        $('#widecolumn').css('min-height', content_height);
    };


    if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 6 ){
        $(window).scroll(function(){ 
            $('#sidebar').css({
                top: $(window).scrollTop()
            });
        })
    }
}
```

I am sort of lost of what to do next....and how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Hm small screens are a problem either way since the sidebar is almost 600 px high so on netbooks it probably won't fit in the browser window at all.

But you could leave the sidebar on position absolute until the sidebar reaches the top when scrolling and then switch to position fixed so it stays at the top of the screen.
That way it will use the available screen height

Comment: I mean how would i figure out when the sidebar has hit the bottom

Comment: in the window scroll event check if scrollTop is higher than your header height, then set the sidebar to fixed