# How do I use scrollTop when trying to figure out sidebar position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539926/how-do-i-get-the-sidebar-to-move-up) yesterday and the answer I go mentioned that I should check if scrollTop is higher than your header height. My question is how do I do this with query. How do I do this when different people have different screen sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('selector').height ()` will return the height of the first element to match the selector in pixels.  It's all in the manual.

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: You should also look at innerHeight() and outerHeight() as well

Comment: I will look at both, but will this take into account the sidebar going off the screen. I basically need the sidebar to move up as the user moves down based on the users screen resolution